# Pulling the value of the actual span tag, but it's a variable

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying the pull the actual span tag of 'plr game4 star' in the html below where 'game4' is a variable that could be between 'game1' and 'game9'.  I managed to pull the class, but it's pulling the whole thing  as **span class="plr game4 star" data-test-id="game-rating"></span** when all I want is **span class="plr game4 star"** or even better, just **plr game4 star**

```
HTML:

<span class="no-wrap">&nbsp;(<span class="plr game4 star" data-test-id="game-rating"></span>)</span>

MY CODE:

player = item.find('span', {'class': lambda L: L and L.startswith('plr')})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.attrs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) method to get attributes as dictionary with each attribute being individual key.

```
player = item.find('span', {'class': lambda L: L and L.startswith('plr')})
result = ' '.join(player.attrs['class'])
```

This will give you:

```
plr game4 star
```